# Java 8 support with Jersey framework

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, option-type

I have a Rest Application using Jersey framework and maven. My application works well. Now I have decided to re-factor my code and use Java 8 features wherever possible. I started with Optional class. But when I use Optional.ifPresent method in my code, tomcat fails to start with Exception.
Note: There are no compilation errors though.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>something</groupId>
<artifactId>project_name</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>my project</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>WhereBy</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Api.java

```
@POST
@Path("/logout")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response logoutUser(@FormParam("email") String email){
    int status = 400;
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    try{
        String msg;
        if (email==null)
            json.addProperty("error", "invalid parameters");
        else{
            Optional<UserSchema> user = UserDAO.getUserByCredentials(email, Optional.empty());
            //user.ifPresent(x -> UserDAO.updateIsActive(x.getEmail(), 0));
            if(user.isPresent()) {
                status = 200;
                UserDAO.updateIsActive(user.get().getEmail(), 0);    //0 = inactive
            }else
                json.addProperty("error", "invalid user credentials");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        json.addProperty("error", "exception occured");
    }
    return Response.status(status).entity(json.toString()).build();
}
```

Here, as you can see that I want to call some function if user object is not null. Now with this code everything works fine, but if I use ifPresent function (commented out in the code), tomcat throws Exception while starting up.

Tomcat localhost log:

```
03-Oct-2016 12:09:11.836 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:223)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

03-Oct-2016 12:09:11.836 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [jersey-serlvet] in web application [/WhereBy] threw load() exception
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:223)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How is this huge chunk of code related to `Optional.ifPresent`? Your code does not even use it. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: When I comment out Optional.ifPresent then it works fine. This error shows up only when I try to use Optional.ifPresent

Comment: The problem is not specific to Optional, but to lambdas and class file format. You seem to be using an outdated version of the ASM, which doesn't understand Java 8.

Comment: Yes @MarkoTopolnik seems like you are right. But what do you mean by ASM? and how do I update it?

Comment: ASM is a bytecode manipulation library that Jersey uses to do its magic.

Comment: Latest Jersey is 2.23.2, or 1.19.2 on the 1.x, so you can see that your 1.8 is *ancient*, and it includes an old 3.1 asm.jar file. You may not be able to update to latest asm without also updating Jersey, and Jersey 1.19.2 doesn't even *use* asm anymore. --- *Suggestion:* Upgrade or don't use Java 8 features.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I managed to update to Jersey 2.23.2. Do you guys mind rating my question since I am new to stackoverflow and it got negatively rated because of poor questioning style. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your jersey version. See issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2429

Upgrading to 1.19 should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to update to Jersey 2.23.2 and I have no issues now :)