# SEVERE: Servlet /CourseGame threw load() exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 56112

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I am implementing Java api with JERSERY Library and CORS for passing data to the other domain. But unfortunately, i got an error as follow.

```
SEVERE: Servlet /CourseGame threw load() exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 56112
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:100)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:672)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:703)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at 

 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Do anyone having solution or facing similar situation on this same ?

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency> -->


     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I am testing this application on locally.
I am having facing above mention problem and in addition to that i have used above dependency.
Do anyone having the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Java 8, the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is typical when you use Java 8 with a Version of Jersey which is not Java8-Compliant (i.e. Version 1.8 in your case).
For more details, see: [Java 8 support with Jersey framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835973/java-8-support-with-jersey-framework)

Comment: Thank you so much. That is precisely what happened to me. I used a lambda expression that upset Jersey so much that it refused to start.